# trouble with importing gcloud libs in python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I have updated gcloud components.  I have installed BigQuery lib using pip install following the instructions in the online doc. I am running Python 2.7.10.

when I run a python script that has the following line:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

it returns the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

I tried python 3.6 and still get the same error.

I did reintsall google sdk and still got the same error.

if I do touch /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python‌​2.7/site-packages/go‌​ogle/**init**.py then import google woudl work, but not import google.cloud

any help is appreciated.

Comment: the cloud shell error is because you haven't specified a project id.

Comment: Amber, when I do "gcloud config list project"  it does show my project name.  So its set.  In fact the project was already set to the project that I had selected before opening the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SDK is not enough. Just use `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery

Comment: I had tried that too. Python virtual env seems to be the only way to make it work.

Comment: virtual env and direct pip usage is the same. You have either more python versions installed or some other problem in the python site-packages, when pip does not work for you.